# Populating Empty Tables in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like to have a JFrame window with an initial empty table of say, 10 columns. An action event generated by a mouse click should then populate the table with a list of 10 or less items, the leaving the used rows of the table empty. How should this be done?

Comment: I am not asking for the full code, just if you could tell me if it's possible and which methods should be used exactly...thanks!

Comment: "10 or less" is kind of vague...

Comment: You want to fill the table then empty it? Can you describe it more?

Comment: I have an initial empty table of 10 rows, I just want to populate new content in 6 of these rows, thus leaving the remaining 4 empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you should create a **DefaultTableModel** with the data you want, and for the blank lines, you fill the object table with **null** values.

It´s simpler with some code:

As I don't know where you data come from, I'll presume it come from a matrix with less than 10 rows:

```
String data[][] = {{"a","b"}, {"c","d"}};
```

you have to create a new matrix with your previous data and the **null** cells for completion of the table. In the end You'll have something like this.

```
Object data2[][] = {{"a","b"}, 
{"c","d"}, 
{null,null}, 
{null,null}, 
{null,null}, 
{null,null}, 
{null,null}, 
{null,null}, 
{null,null}, 
{null,null}};
```

This way you'll have a 10x2 matrix that will fill your table. Now you can update your **DefaultTableModel**

```
yourTable.setModel(
        new DefaultTableModel(data2, new String [] {"Column1Title", "Cloumn2Title"}) {
        Class[] types = new Class[] {String.class,String.class}; 
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[] {true, true};
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex){ return types [columnIndex];}
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex){ return canEdit [columnIndex];}
});
```

And that's it. I presume you don't have problems to create your **Object** matrix.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend defining your own `TableModel` implementation by subclassing [`AbstractTableModel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html).  That way you can "back" your model with any suitable collection (e.g. `java.util.List`).  When an ActionEvent is fired you would typically amend your underlying collection and then fire a `TableModelEvent` to cause the `JTable` to be repainted.

Comment: Can you please give me a brief example?

Comment: @Vijay: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Answer (score 0):

Besides creating your own TableModel as explained by Adamski, you can use the [javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) directly.
It has a constructor which takes the number of columns and rows as argument and methods to manage the data (`addRow`, `insertRow`, `setDataAt`, ...).

I would prefer creating an own TableModel, unless it's for a very simple program/functionality.